# Play video when thumbnail is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a beginner of JavaScript. I want to play a mp4 file from a specific time for a certain time in HTML5. First, I want to load a thumbnail image. And if it is clicked, I'd like to play the video file from the particular time. This is my code. But it doesn't work. What did I do wrong?

```
function PlayVideo(aid, vid) {
    var video = document.getElementById(vid);
    video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function () {
        videoStartTime = 6;
        videoEndTime = 7;
        this.currentTime = videoStartTime;
    }, false);

    video.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
        if (this.currentTime > videoEndTime) {
            this.pause();
            this.currentTime = 6;
        }
    });

    document.getElementById(aid).style.display = "none";
}
```

And in the body of the HTML file:

```
<a id = "anchor" onclick = "PlayVideo('anchor','vid');">
    <img src = "test.jpg" alt = "trail" />
</a>
<video id = "vid" controls width = "320">
  <source src = "test.mp4" type = "video/mp4"/>
</video>
```

Comment: what part of your code fails? does the thumbnail load? does it play but not the correct duration? please elaborate.

Comment: The thumnail is successfully loaed. But when I clicked it, the video player is loaded, but it doesn't start automatically. And when I play it, it doesn't start from 6 sec. It just starts from the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot see you start the video anywhere:

```
function PlayVideo(aid, vid) {

    var video = document.getElementById(vid);
    video.play();  // <- start play

    //...
}
```

You can also listen to the `canplay` event in global to know when a video can be started.

Comment: Thanks. But it still starts from the beginning, not from 6.

Comment: @user1610952 and it you set currenttime right after play() (check if it's not equal 6).

Comment: Hm... You mean this?: var video = document.getElementById(vid);           video.play();this.currentTime = 6;